# How do you use XMLSerialize for Enum typed properties in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a simple enum:

```
enum simple 
{ 
  one, 
  two, 
  three 
};
```

I also have a class that has a property of type `simple`. I tried decorating it with the attribute: `[XmlAttribute(DataType = "int")]`. However, it fails when I try to serialize it using an `XmlWriter`.

What is the proper way to do this? Do I have to mark the enum itself as well as the property, and if so, with which data type?

Answer (score 55):

As per Darin Dimitrov's answer - only extra thing I'd point out is that if you want control over how your enum fields are serialized out then you can decorate each field with the [XmlEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
public enum Simple
{
      [XmlEnum(Name="First")]
      one,
      [XmlEnum(Name="Second")]
      two,
      [XmlEnum(Name="Third")]
      three,
}
```

Comment: Please, do not forget mark enum with [Serializable] attribute.

Comment: @Anton, what if the class is already marked as Serializable? do we still need to mark the ENUM separately as Serializable?

Comment: I followed your method as well as the code in above; but I still get following error in VB.net code. 

```Enum underlying type and the object must be same type or object. Type passed in was 'System.String'; the enum underlying type was 'System.Int32'.```

Nothing special in class... just a test class with one property and one enum.

Answer (score 24):

There shouldn't be any problems serializing enum properties:

```
public enum Simple { one, two, three }

public class Foo
{
    public Simple Simple { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Console.OpenStandardOutput()))
        {
            var foo = new Foo
            {
                Simple = Simple.three
            };
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(foo.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
        }
    }
}
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Simple>three</Simple>
</Foo>
```

Comment: That works but it makes the enum property an element not an attribute. When I try to make it an attribute it fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try decorating the property with XmlAttribute: `[XmlAttribute("simple")]public Simple Simple { get; set; }`

Comment: Properties don't seem able to be decorated. Fields only, correct?

Comment: I might have a related problem - I used a [generate-classes-from-schema tool](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator) (not `xsd`) which may have over- (under?) attributed the properties, because in my case the enum properties aren't being included in the serialization.  They