# Attributes and elements missing from serialized object

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I have some generated proxy classes, that contain properties with the XMLAttribute attribute, e.g.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0301")]
public Verwerkingssoort verwerkingssoort
{
    get
    {
        return this.verwerkingssoortField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.verwerkingssoortField = value;
    }
}
```

This and several other properties don't show up in the SOAP message however. The proxies were generated using svcutil.

As I'm writing this question I notice that the properties that do show up as attributes are strings, while this is an Enum (but I haven't done a thorough check, yet). Does somebody know if this is the problem, or what else it could be and what possible solutions there are?

**Update:**
After some more checking, I found that no Enums are included as attribute, but Strings and Bools work fine.

**Update 2:**
In a [simple case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306299/how-do-you-use-xmlserialize-for-enum-typed-properties-in-c) an Enum as attribute is serialized just fine.

**Update 3:**
If I replace `XmlAttributeAttribute(...)` with `XmlIgnoreAttribute()` and add the following property:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("verwerkingssoort")]
public string verwerkingssoortString
{
    get
    {
        return this.verwerkingssoortField.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        this.verwerkingssoortField = (Verwerkingssoort)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Verwerkingssoort), value, true);
    }
}
```

it works fine, but making changes like this throughout the generated code would be a rather Herculean task, and when the contract changes, I would need to do it all over again. So I'm still looking for a better solution.

**Update 4:**
It turns out that this problem is not limited to attributes. I just noticed that a property that should be serialized to an element is omitted as well. The same things apply: it is an Enum, and it works fine if I change it to a string.

Thanks, regards,

Miel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `Type` property of the `XmlAttributeAttribute` class to the type of your enum?

Comment: When I try that in the referenced simple case, I get an excpetion (in Dutch :( ), that the Type for XmlAttribute can not be given for primitive types.