# Losing values between Client and Service WCF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

When I set some values on an object in my client controller and then step through the debugger as far as I can, I end up here:

```
public class WCFServiceAuthenticateClientBehavior : IEndpointBehavior, IClientMessageInspector
{

    public WCFServiceAuthenticateClientBehavior(
        HttpRequestBase request,
        string authTokenAlias = "authToken",
        string ajaxTokenAlias = "ajaxToken")
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        request.Headers.Add(...etc); // last call before service is here

        return null;
    }

}
```

If I open the Immediate Window, I can print `request.toString()` and see that the XML has the values that I expect. For example this value:

`<d4p1:AccrualRevenueRecognition>AccrualEvenly</d4p1:AccrualRevenueRecognition>`

However when the breakpoint at my Service method is hit, inspecting that object shows that `AccrualRevenueRecognition` does not reflect this value from the XML.

**My question is:** 
Is there a place in my service where I can debug earlier, before the method called by my client, to see if the value is lost there?

FWIW, this is only happening with enums and `AccrualRevenueRecognition` is an enum that looks like this:

```
    [DataMember]
    [Column("accrual_revenue_recognition")]
    public byte AccrualRevenueRecognitionId
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte)this.AccrualRevenueRecognition;
        }
        set
        {
            AccrualRevenueRecognition = (AccrualRevenueRecognitionChoices) value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(AccrualRevenueRecognitionChoices))]
    public AccrualRevenueRecognitionChoices AccrualRevenueRecognition { get; set; }

    [DataContract]
    [Flags]
    public enum AccrualRevenueRecognitionChoices
    {
        [EnumMember]
        NotSet = 0,
        [EnumMember]
        AccrualEvenly = 1,
        [EnumMember]
        AccrualAtInvoice = 2,
        [EnumMember]
        AccrualAtPayment = 3
    }
```

The class containing this enum is using `[DataContract, Serializable]` and the method called from the client is using `[VerificationSameOrigin]`.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306299/how-do-you-use-xmlserialize-for-enum-typed-properties-in-c help?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working and despite it being a hacky solution, I hope it helps someone else:

```
var success = this.Client.MyServiceCall(
    new myObject
    {
        // Because WCF obliterates the enum, casting to byte for its respective ID is needed:
        AccrualRevenueRecognitionId = (byte)viewModel.QualityOfFinancials.AccrualRevenueRecognition,
        CashRevenueRecognitionId = (byte)viewModel.QualityOfFinancials.CashRevenueRecognition
    }
);
```

This works because in my class, I am actually storing the int in the DB:

```
[DataMember]
[Column("accrual_revenue_recognition")]
public byte AccrualRevenueRecognitionId
{
    get
    {
        return (byte)this.AccrualRevenueRecognition;
    }
    set
    {
        AccrualRevenueRecognition = (AccrualRevenueRecognitionChoices) value;
    }
}
```